# smptlib - trying to send email in Hebrew but getting some encoding instead

Tags: smtp, ascii, decode, encode, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email which written in Hebrew.
I'm getting the text in some encoding instead.
I tried to google that error but still cant solve the problem.

```
import smtplib
import time
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

service = Service("C:\Development\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

SUPERFARM_URL = "https://shop.super-pharm.co.il/"
my_email = "ZZZ"
password = "ZZZ"

driver.get(SUPERFARM_URL)
time.sleep(2)
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'search-input')
search_bar.send_keys("סימילאק גולד")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
```

The issue is in these lines:

```
similac_gold_price = int(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="results-boxes"]/a[3]/div/div[2]').get_attribute(
    "textContent").strip().split(" ")[-1].strip())
similac_gold_price_dec = int(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="results-boxes"]/a[3]/div/div[2]').get_attribute(
    "textContent").strip().split(" ")[0].strip())
similac_grams = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="results-boxes"]/a[4]/div/div[3]/div/div/span[1]').get_attribute("textContent")
similac_grams_encode = u' '.join(similac_grams).encode('utf-8').strip()

if similac_gold_price < 70:
    # The "text_encode" and "similac_grams_encode" are in Hebrew.
    text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="results-boxes"]/a[3]/div/div[3]/div/h4').get_attribute('textContent')
    text_encode = u' '.join(text).encode('utf-8').strip()
    print(text)
    print(text_encode)
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
        connection.sendmail(
            from_addr=my_email,
            to_addrs="CCC",
            msg=f"Subject:Similac Offer!\n\n{text_encode} with a price of {similac_gold_price}.{similac_gold_price_dec} ({similac_grams_encode})"
        )
```

I tried to get plain Hebrew, but got text in some encoding instead.
The email I'm getting:

> b'\xd7\xa1 \xd7\x99 \xd7\x9e \xd7\x99 \xd7\x9c \xd7\x90 \xd7\xa7 \xc2\xa0 \xd7\xa1 \xd7\x99 \xd7\x9e \xd7\x99 \xd7\x9c \xd7\x90 \xd7\xa7   \xd7\x92 \xd7\x95 \xd7\x9c \xd7\x93   \xd7\xa2 \xd7\x9d   H M O   \xd7\xa9 \xd7\x9c \xd7\x91   2' with a price of 69.90 (b'7 0 0   \xd7\x92 \xd7\xa8 \xd7\x9d')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument to sendmail needs to be a properly formatted MIME message, not free-form text.

Something like this;

```
from email.message import EmailMessage()
...
    message = EmailMessage()
    message["from"] = my_email
    message["to"] = "example1@gmail.com"
    message["subject"] = "Similac Offer!"
    message.set_content(f"{text_encode} with a price of {similac_gold_price}.{similac_gold_price_dec} ({similac_grams_encode})")

    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
        connection.send_message(message)
```

This should convert your Hebrew text into a suitable character set (probably UTF-8 in practice) and create the necessary MIME structure around it to communicate the correct character set to the recipient's email client.

See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html (and maybe notice that you can find a lot of older code on the net which uses `MimeMultipart` and other obsolete libraries; you want the new API, always).

Comment: Hi, with this edit im getting only an empty email..

Comment: OK i figured the answer. instead of:  ' message.set_content = "some text" ', its :message.set_content("some text")

Comment: My bad; thanks for catching that!