Send email with hebrew text in python - get error: Violation of BIDI requirement 3
I want to send an email in Python that includes text in Hebrew and English, but I keep getting an error: Failed to send email. Error: Violation of BIDI requirement 3
I tried different solutions, but nothing solved the problem
I try to use utf-8, in html to use dir="rtl" or "ltr" and use EmailMessage - nothing help:(
it is the code:
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
def send_email(to_email, subject, body, html=False):
    smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    smtp_port = 587
    from_email = 'XXXXX@gmail.com' 
    email_password = 'XXXXX'  

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = from_email
    msg['To'] = to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    if html:
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
    else:
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(from_email, email_password)
        server.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msg.as_string())
        server.quit()
        print("Email sent successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to send email. Error: {e}")


This is probably an encoding issue, try something like what's done here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361719/smptlib-trying-to-send-email-in-hebrew-but-getting-some-encoding-instead) or here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58166674/18189622).

import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Gmail credentials
sender_email = "from_addr@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "to_addr@gmail.com"
password = "Gmail App Password"

# Create message container
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = sender_email
msg['To'] = receiver_email
msg['Subject'] = "utf8 test mail"

# Body of the email
body = """This is the body of the email.
זה הוא גוף ההודעה."""
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

try:
    # Set up the server using Gmail's SMTP server
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()  # Secure the connection
    server.login(sender_email, password)  # Login to your email account

    # Send the email
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, text)

    print("Email sent successfully!")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to send email. Error: {e}")

finally:
    # Close the connection
    server.quit()


thank you:)
I try it but still get the same error...
Failed to send email. Error: Violation of BIDI requirement 3

Sounds like an editor issue. I guess your IDE encodes Hebrew characters differently. Try this using VIM
